# MyBatis - Convert query-check from a single object to check on a collection

Tags: java, mybatis

Have the following piece of code.

**Select** bunch of columns **from** table **where** ... **left join** ...**where**

```
<if test="taskowner != null">
    AND (o.primary_taskowner_id = #{taskowner.id}
         OR o.secondary_taskowner_id = #{taskowner.id})
</if>
```

In this case *taskowner* is a single selected object in my **combobox**.

Requirements have changed, and now I need **combo box-multi select**. How can I adjust that piece of a query to combo box-multi select(I want to run the same condition but on each object in the collection)?

I came up with this:

```
<if test="taskowners != null and taskowners.empty == false">

     AND o.primary_taskowner_id 
    <foreach item="taskowner" collection="taskowners" open="(" separator="," close=")">
         #{taskowner.id}
   </foreach>

    OR o.secondary_taskowner_id 
    <foreach item="taskowner" collection="taskowners" open="(" separator="," close=")">
         #{taskowner.id}
    </foreach>
</if>
```

But the result is not what I am expecting. I tried multiple variations of that solution, but none of them worked. And haven't found anything helpful online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain the desired logic, perhaps with example SQL.  do you want something like `x in (a, b, c) or y in (q, r, s)`?  that appears to be what you have written.

Comment: Step 1 is to create a SQL DML that does what you want (for 3 or  elements).

Comment: @DwB I have a collection of task owners; each task owner has some_id. I want to join rows where some_id = primary_taskowner_id, if with that  primary_taskowner_id nothing was found then check where some_id = secondary_taskowner_id. And I want to execute that check on each collection entry.

Comment: exactly, write the SQL for that and the MyBatis implementation will become straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Thanks to [DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453005/dwb) for showing me the right direction.

```
<if test="taskowners != null and taskowners.empty == false">

    AND (o.primary_taskowner_id IN
    <foreach item="taskowner" collection="taskowners" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{taskowner.id}
    </foreach>

    OR o.secondary_taskowner_id IN
    <foreach item="taskowner" collection="taskowners" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{taskowner.id}
    </foreach>)
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the SQL you want is a variation of this:

```
... and
(o.prim_id = '7' or o.second_id = '7') or
(o.prim_id = '8' or o.second_id = '8') or
(o.prim_id = '9' or o.second_id = '9') ...
```

Use one foreach loop to generate this.
The MyBatis "code" will be something like this:

```
AND
(
<foreach ...blah>
   (o.prim_id = {tid} or o.second_id = {tid})
   <conditional or> (I'm sure mybatis provides this, but I dont remember the syntax.
</foreach>
)
```